# Google custom search API specify image size range?

Tags: javascript, c#, google-api, google-custom-search

I want images >=640px wide and >=360px tall only.

Questions:

1) Can I use those exact parameters in the Google custom search API?

2) If not, what sizes do the strings "large", "xlarge", "xxlarge" actually corelate to?

3) Can I use comma separated values for the imageSize like "large,xlarge,xxlarge"?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to search for multiple sizes, too (mainly your 3rd question). Any luck yet? Because I tried the pipe ("|") and comma as a separator and that didn't work..

Comment: @REJH Turned out in the end we just made multiple VB.NET threads to do each size individually.